# Sappho Lobel-Page 136: to amend, or not to amend?

Tags: greek, poetry, declension, sappho

The fragment is reported by the tradition as:

> Ἦρος ἄγγελος ἱμερόφωνος ἀήδων

Or sometimes with ἡμερόφωνος. It would seem we just need to fix a psilosis for the third word. However, Edmonds and safopoemas amend the last word to ἀήδω, and Lobel-Page and Campbell put all but the first word in cruces, with Lobel-Page adding «Aut ἀήδω aut ἄγγελον ἰμερόφωνον scribendum», as if the accusative was the only form in -nu. Voigt says that is "praeter necessitatem". So, what gives?

> What reasons do we have to amend or to not amend this?